# How to Fix "actual and formal argument lists differ in length" using methods?

Tags: java

I am using methods doing an assignment and I can't get `getBidAmounts` method to pass. I keep getting this kind of error:

`required: int[],int found: int[] reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

      double budget = getBudget();
      final double MIN_BID_AMOUNT = 0;

      final int MIN_NUM_BIDS = 0;
      final int MAX_NUM_BIDS = 100;
      int numBids = getNumBids(MIN_NUM_BIDS, MAX_NUM_BIDS);
      int[] bids = new int[numBids];
      getBidAmounts(bids);
      }

      public static void getBidAmounts (int[] bidAmounts, int minBidAmount) {
         for (int i = 0; i < bidAmounts.length; i++) {
         do {
            bidAmounts[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Amount of Bid #" + (i+1) + ": "));
            if (bidAmounts[i] <= minBidAmount)
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a Valid Bid Amount Above" + minBidAmount + ".");
            }
         } while (bidAmounts[i] <= minBidAmount);
        }
     }
```

This should allow the user to input things into the array.

Comment: `getBidAmounts(bids)` second argument missing from function call. You need to pass something for `minBidAmount`

Comment: What do you believe the value of parameter `minBidAmount` will be in method `getBidAmounts` when you don't pass a value in the `getBidAmounts(bids)` method call, and why do you believe that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `getBidAmounts(bids);` you're supplying just one parameter, while

`public static void getBidAmounts (int[] bidAmounts, int minBidAmount)` expects two arguments.

So, **change** `getBidAmounts(bids);` to `getBidAmounts(bids,`**`MIN_NUM_BIDS`**`);`.

Here, `MIN_NUM_BIDS` will represent the argument `minBidAmount` (second one) inside the `getBidAmounts` method.